# How to add jasper reporting to JHipster project?

Tags: jasper-reports, jhipster

I've generated a jhipster 4 project with uaa, a microservice and a gateway and running with consul. All works well. now i don't know how to add jasper reporting to my project. All help would be welcomed.

**EDIT :** To be more precise, is it relevant to build a micro-service for jasper reporting (Exported to json format) ? And is there a particular angular component to display these reports ?

Comment: Have you tried and failed ? If so, add more details, if not, maybe look there for the maven dependency : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.1.0 and there for a quick example : https://github.com/gauravbrills/jasperreportswithspringboot. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  matthieusb, in fact, I've not yet tried anything. At the architectural level, I'd like to know if it is relevant to build a micro service for jasper reporting? Knowing that our micro service will produce reports in json format, is there an Angular component to display them?

Comment: First, you should edit your question and explicitely ask what you just told me. And to answer your question : of course you can display json with angular, using data binding. The "Tour of heroes" of Angular 2 tutorial will help you do understand the core concepts. I don't know if using jasper report is relevant for you, maybe someone else can answer that.

Comment: Thank u for the link. The question did not concern the relevance of using jasper for reporting in my project, but rather whether it is relevant in a distributed architecture with microservices, to have a microservice for reporting?